# How to preserve the color of a line pattern fill color in categorized vector layer?

Tags: qgis, color, vector-layer, fill

I am applying different colors to a vector layer. Now I wanted to improve it, and get some items also with a crossed pattern. I want to have the hatching black, and the colors remaining. All I can get, is the hatching in the same color as the fill - despite having it in the symbol set to black. At the link below, a screenshot can be found.

[image]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Lock layer color** button on the line pattern fill's line symbol:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To assign the color of the fill, click on "Simple fill" and then assign the color from there.

If you set it from "fill" (the one that is selected in your screenshot) the color of the pattern is also impacted (Qgis 2.14.3)